# How to add an external login to ASP.NET Core identity tables

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have a SPA (vue3) and an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I'm trying to implement Google authentication in my app

The user will use his Google account to login from the front end and Google API will return a JWT token.

What I want to do is take the token and send it to the ASP.NET Core Web API in order to add the user to the identity tables (`Users`, `UserLogins`, `UserClaims` etc...)

Is there any built-in method I can use to achieve this?

I tried many tutorials on the internet but they only explain ASP.NET Core MVC, not Web API.

Comment: Have you read this? https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Comment: i did. i i have no problem with the js front end . the bach end i'm asking for

Comment: But what part of the backend? Authentication? Microsoft Identity? OAuth2? Or just "how do I store provide an endpoint" or "how do I store a token in the database"? Your question is not clear

Comment: @JHBonarius how to store users data in my  database that came from the Google token so i can associte them with  roles...

Comment: on `Identity Core` there is `IdentityUserContext` and `IdentityDbContext`. if you want to support external login, then use `IdentityDbContext` which will include external login support.

Comment: There is no single solution to this. You could use Microsoft Identity for the user model, combine that with OpenID connect and OAuth2 to the Google Identity. But usually tokens are short lived and associated with a user, so your association with roles seems specific to your application.